# About uploading app to Play Store

Tags: android, file-upload, google-play

I have two questions about uploading app to play store. First of all I want to upload two versions of my app, the first one is free with adds and the second one is paid without any adds, but is the same app in both cases.

What should I do to upload both apps? I had thought about changing the package name but the problem I think I will have is that if the user downloads the free version and then pays for the premium he will have both applications in his smartphone, the premium won't override the free one.

And this question is more about your experience uploading apps. I have mine in english, spanish and french. I had thought in uploading the app in every country but in the videos I have seen everyone chooses a few countries to upload their own apps. What do you recommend me to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. upload first version with ads. 2. change version number and upgrade same app without ads in play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle it, though I have to say I'm not sure you should.

My suggestion is to upload your free version first, and later when you have enough users implement in app billing instead.
I know it's not directly answering your question, but I think it's a better approach that will save you a lot of time, and also be a better experience to the users.

Regarding countries, you don't need to upload it to each country, that's automatic (unless you indicate otherwise), and you actually can't upload or create a specific store listing by country, at least as far as I know.

**You do need** to create a store listing to the languages you want, otherwise they'll get the default language and in some cases see automatic translated listing, which is quite bad in my opinion.

Comment: first of all thank you for your response. I'm going to do it the way you suggested me, first of all I will upload the free version and then if I have enough users I will upload the billing app.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you

Comment: In relation to the countries, I was thinking for example in German (or maybe another launguage not as common), my app is not going to have that language but the first language is English (the one defined in strings.xml) so lot of german people may know English. Should I include this country? And of course the description in Play Store won't be in German, it will be in English.

Sorry for sending the answer before finishing it.

Comment: When you say "include this country", what do you mean?

Comment: I mean allowing Google Play to distribute the application in every country and if they don't have the original language, the app will be launched in English (I programmed it to be like that). In this youtube video it is seen from the minute 8:15 the screen where the developer chooses the each country instead of choosing every country. What do you think I should do, just choosing the countries the app has their original languages or choose every country https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-09v8aSAbA  
Sorry for my English.
Many thanks.

Comment: I think it depends on the kind of application, but generally, I usually make my apps available everywhere. 
You do need to consider where is your primary audience so you'll choose the best default language for Google Play's listing.

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one app, which is free to download, and implement an in-app payment in that app through which a user can choose to make a payment in exchange for the removal of ads, without the need to download a separate ad-free app.  This is the standard approach to the problem you have described.

If you implement separate apps, your ratings will be spread across both apps, to the probable detriment of the rankings of both in the Play store's search results.  Also, an upgrade to the ad-free version will require the user to download the paid version, which creates a barrier to selling it.  Finally, once a user who has tried the free app decided to pay for removal of ads, they would almost certainly uninstall the free version, which might cause the store to see that app as being unsatisfactory to your users.